# How to compute Euler angles for a 3-axis gimbal with a stuck axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

**The problem**

I have a 2-axis gimbal that orients a laser beam. This gimbal is located at point *G*.

In order to drive the gimbal, I need to feed it with 2 intrinsic Tait-Bryan angles (sometimes improperly called Euler angles), which rotate the laser in that order:
*X(roll) -> Z'(yaw) -> Y''(pitch)*

The motor driving the X axis is stuck at a fixed angle *fixedRoll*.

I want my laser to hit a target point *P* in world coordinates. How do I compute *yaw* and *pitch*?

(notice that even though *fixedRoll* cannot be changed, for a same target point *P* in world coordinates, a different *fixedRoll* will lead to different values for *yaw* and *pitch*).

---

**What I did so far**

1. I computed a "Look At" rotation matrix *L* like this:

   - Column vector *L1* contains a normalized version of *GP* in world coordinates
   - Column vector *L2* is a normalized version of *Up x L1* (cross product), where Up is the column vector *(0, 0, 1)*
   - Column vector L3 is *L1 x L2*
2. I computed the rotation matrix *Xf* corresponding to *fixedRoll*
3. I computed the full rotation matrix *R = L.Xf*
4. I used the XZY formula from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles?oldformat=true#Rotation_matrix) to compute the intrinsic Euler angles from R. The results doesn't look good to me, as the computed *roll* is not equal to *fixedRoll*. Am I right to think that it should be?
5. To investigate further, I used the YZX formula to compute the **extrinsic** Euler angles. Same thing: I expected the computed *roll* to be equal to *fixedRoll* as well, but it's not the case.

Maybe I did something wrong in my calculations but, as a starting point, would you say that my approach to the problem is correct?

---

**EDIT: second approach**

I tried another approach: instead of computing the full rotation matrix with *R = L.Xf*, I computed it directly like this:

- Column vector *L1* contains a normalized version of *GP* in world coordinates
- Column vector *L2* is a normalized version of *Up x L1*, where Up is the column vector *(0, sin(-fixedRoll), cos(-fixedRoll))*
- Column vector *L3* is *L1 x L2*

My feeling is that my 2 approaches should be equivalent, but obviously they are not. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by a "Look At" rotation matrix. or the "rotation matrix corresponding to fixedRoll"? If your gimbal is already oriented to this fixed angle, then the intrinsic roll angle you want is $0$, as the "intrinsic" roll angle is measured from its current position, so anything other than $0$ will command it to change the roll angle. How are you measuring the vector $GP$? With respect to global coordinates or the "intrinsic" coordinates of the gimbal's current position?

Comment: Also please clarify what system of angles you need. You say "Euler" angles, but then talk about "yaw, pitch, roll", which are Tait-Bryan angles, not Euler angles.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair, I edited my question to answer your points.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming (you didn't answer this part of my question) that $X_f$ rotates the vector indicated in your second approach to "Up", aka, the positive $z$ axis. This is why you feel your second approach should be the same as the first.

But what it doesn't rotate is $GP$. So when you construct $L$ in the second attempt, you are constructing it from one vector that is unchanged between the two, and one that has been rotated. The result is a different $L$ than the first attempt - and one that is not different by just a rotation about the $x$-axis. But in the first attempt when you compose with $X_f$, you are rotating the action of $L$ - effectively the same as rotating both $GP$ and "Up".

The "Look At" construction gives a rotation that brings the positive $x$-axis to point towards $P$, while also keeping the positive $z$-axis in the same plane as $GP$ and "Up". By rotating the Up vector first, you changed that to keep the roll constant. But in your first attempt, $L$ doesn't hold roll constant. So after you set the starting roll with $X_f$, it proceeded to change the roll. And that is why the total rotation had the wrong roll.